Flutter reuse Matrix4 transformation for InteractiveViewer across different screen sizes
I need to apply the Matrix4 transformation to my image wrapped inside a InteractiveViewer. Images are always in 3:4 ratio
It works OK on the original device that modify the Matrix4 (pan/zoom), problem is when I send the Matrix4 values to another device (Tablet for example) to load the same image and reuse the Matrix4 transformation, it is not the same, so I suspected it might be because of the screen sizes.
The Matrix4 is sent as String message using String.fromCharCodes(matrix4.storage.buffer.asUint8List())
I tried sending the scale value and translate offset separately to use Transform.scale() and Transform.translate() but it does not work very well.
My layout is as below:
Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 9/16,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                return ClipRect(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: InteractiveViewer(
                      transformationController: _controller,
                      child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

My question is: How can I reuse the same Matrix4 transformation to produce the same result regardless of devices and screen sizes?

@pskink Sorry for being unclear, the images are always in 3:4 ratio and the page is a AspectRatio widget of 9:16. I can detect positon of tap event to zoom in on the image at exact location on each device by sending the offset like (dx/constraints.maxWidth)(dy/constraints.maxHeight) and retrieve it on other device like (constraints.maxWidth * dx)(constraints.maxHeight * dy) using the method from link.

So when I zoom/pan an image, I don't know how to scale the matrix before send and how to scale it back based on other device's screen sizes. Is it achievable using matrix4?

Thanks alot for the direction, unfortunately I have not success yet, I have trouble with the scale factor, by calling getMaxScaleOnAxis, you already have the latest scale applied to the InteractiveViewer, why do we need to multiply it to a factor (0.3 in your sample) on remote side? When I tried to modify your sample to use the scale factor returned from InteractiveViewer.onInteractionUpdate (scale*ScaleUpdateDetails.scale), the result is not the same.

Here's the demo between my phone and a tablet: link

0.3  was just any example factor, check my updated gist: now its more like your AspectRatio 9:16 case - the scale is: scale: scale * remoteSize.width / localSize.width

i made it a bit more simple: now localSize.width is not needed on remote side (its part of scale), also matrix computation is more simple now, check my final gist

Something's off, this time I follow exactly your gist, when zoom in on local side, the photo on remote side is zoom out all the way to a tiny dot. I tried running the sample code from your gist on a phone and a tablet using hard coded value, the result is also off.

Thank you for the follow up, I see now, the only difference was my InteractiveViewer was constrained: true instead of unconstrained. When I turned it to false, it WORKS perfectly. This basically answers my question but the unconstrained image is too much zoomed in initially and since there is no initial scale property, I think i will have to do some tricks. Thanks man, you are a life saver. Do you mind posting your solution above as an separate answer so I can accept it!

"and since there is no initial scale property" - use transformationController: _controller that is initially scaled then, and if you want feel free to post a self answer

@pskink Hate to trouble you again, seems like InteractiveViewer has its fair share of issues regarding the initial scale going on here github.  So I tried switching back to constrained: true and getting the offsetX and offsetY from local matrix and divide them by localSize.width and localSize.height and send them instead of anchor, on remote side, i retrieve by multiply them with remoteSize.width and remoteSize.height but no success yet. Do you think this can be done with constrained: true ?

"Do you think this can be done with constrained: true ?" - i dont think so, with constrained: true its quite hard to control how the child is drawn while if constrained: false you can control it completely, so whats the problem with calculating the initial value of TranformationController? you dont know the size of the child (your image)?

I know the size of my image, problem is with screen sizes again, devices like tablet can display the whole image whereas phones need to scale down to fit like when constrained: true, in those cases, the location is not accurate anymore. E.g: when i place a marker. If I just apply the initial scale on every devices then on some it will be like this: link. So I'm thinking if I can extract the offset from the matrix and map it to a local position, maybe I can sync with remote side (like when i apply the tap to zoom a specific area). But no hope yet.

If you have interactive viewer size (since you use layout builder) and image size then calculating the initial matrix is easy: https://gist.github.com/pskink/6ef88df64d7764fd0efcd60aa618f0c0

This is it, looks like I'm going with constrained: false after all. Thanks alot for your directions, really save my day.

I'll definitely check that out, thanks mate

All credit goes to @pskink
Problem is I cannot reuse the matrix4 directly on different screen sizes and expect the same result as local device but I have to scale it before sending.
From local side, get the scale and anchor offset like below:
final scale = _controller.getMaxScaleOnAxis() / localSize.width;
final anchor = _controller.toScene(Offset.zero);

And on remote side, apply the scale and translation:
_remoteController.value = Matrix4.identity()
    ..scale(scale * remoteSize.width)
    ..translate(-anchor.dx, -anchor.dy);

localSize and remoteSize can be obtained from LayoutBuilder like:
Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)

Note: The above only works if InteractiveViewer's constrained: false, in case you want to scale the image initial matrix, you can follow the thread here: github
